# A loop that compares individual letters in a string

Tags: java, string, loops

I am trying to compare the letters from the user and a phrase. I want it to walk down each letter. I have "`if ((userGuessLength / phraseLength * 100.0) > 75.0)`" as a place holder to just compare string lengths but need it to compare each letter in the string.

how would I modify it to do so?

**Example:**

Somewhere over the rainbow. - actual phrase

Somewhere over the xxxxxxx. - user guess

19 character are correct (including spaces) 26 characters is the actual phrase length

`(19/26) * 100 = 73` percent (they missed)

This is my whole program:

```
package classprojects;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.util.Random;

public class WordGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String userInput = " "; // userInput 
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner word = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = rand.nextInt(14);
    String underscores = ""; // holder for changing characters to *
    String update = ""; // this is updated from underscores and displayed 
    String[] phrases = new String[15];
    // Phrases used in Array
    phrases[0] = "dog eat dog world";
    phrases[1] = "a penny for your thoughts";
    phrases[2] = "at the drop of a hat";
    phrases[3] = "ball is in your court ";
    phrases[4] = "back to the drawing board ";
    phrases[5] = "barking up the wrong tree";
    phrases[6] = "beat around the bush";
    phrases[7] = "best of both worlds";
    phrases[8] = "bite off more than you can chew";
    phrases[9] = "blessing in disguise";
    phrases[10] = "cant judge a book by its cover";
    phrases[11] = "costs an arm and a leg";
    phrases[12] = "curiosity killed the cat";
    phrases[13] = "dont put all your eggs in one basket";
    phrases[14] = "elvis has left the building";

    double phraseLength = phrases[n].length();
    //loop for changing characters in array to * and replacing correct letter from the userInput
    while (true) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {

            for (int i = 0; i < phraseLength; i++) {
                char theChar = phrases[n].charAt(i);
                if (theChar == ' ') {
                    underscores += ' ';
                    update = underscores;
                } else
                    for (int j = 0; j < userInput.length(); j++) {
                        char compare = userInput.charAt(j);
                        if (theChar == compare) {
                            underscores += compare;
                            update = underscores;
                            break;

                        } else if (j == userInput.length() - 1) {

                            underscores += "*";
                            update = underscores;

                        }

                    }

            }
            //prints the updated phrase with * and letters that were correctly guessed, and prompts user to continue to enter letters
            System.out.println(phrases[n]);
            System.out.println("Start by Entering a Letter to Guess the Phrase: " + update);
            System.out.println("Enter A Letter: ");
            //takes the keyboard input and makes it all lower case and
            //restarts underscores so phrase does not stack 
            String letterGuess = word.next();
            String letterGuessL = letterGuess.toLowerCase();
            userInput += letterGuessL;
            underscores = "";

        }
        //Display after 5 turns
        int userReply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you know the phrase? If not continue guessing.",
                "Guess", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        //if yes then it takes the length of your guess and divides it by the phrase and check if its over 75%
        if (userReply == 0) {
            String userGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your guess?");
            double userGuessLength = userGuess.length();
            if ((userGuessLength / phraseLength * 100.0) > 75.0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct, you WIN! That was the correct phrase: " + phrases[n]);
                break;

            } else {
                int userReply2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "Sorry that is wrong, Do you want to continue going?", "Wrong", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                if (userReply2 == 0) {

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game is OVER. The correct phrase was: " + phrases[n]);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried to solve this problem. Does it work? If not, what does not work?

Comment: Why not take the correct String and place it into a `char[]`, then do the same with the user input. You can then do a direct comparison using indexes and can increment a counter for each correct letter.

Comment: I tried to use a similar for loop from my code where it replaces each letter with * but rather than replace just count

Comment: do you have an example or bare bone code of that I can see Ascalonian?

Comment: Actually, you don't need char[]. What about in a for-loop `if (correctString.charAt(i) == inputString.charAt(i)) { correctCounter++;}` or something - of course, keeping in mind the String lengths

Comment: making sure it uses the shorter of the two strings to compare so it doesn't run into an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Here is one way using a stream instead of an explicit loop:

```
String answer = "Somewhere over the rainbow";
String guess = "Somewhere over the xxxxxxx";
long correct = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(answer.length(), guess.length()))
        .filter(i -> answer.charAt(i) == guess.charAt(i)).count();
int total = Math.max(answer.length(), guess.length());
System.out.format("(%d/%d) = %d%%%n", correct, total, correct*100/total);
```

**Output:**

> (19/26) = 73%

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static double getCorrectness(String actualPhrase, String userGuess) {
    char [] actual = actualPhrase.toCharArray();
    char [] guess = userGuess.toCharArray();
    int length = Math.min(actual.length, guess.length);
    for(int counter = 0;counter<length ;counter++) {
        //case sensitive
        if(actual[counter]!=guess[counter]) {
            return counter*100.0/actual.length;
        }
    }
    return length*100.0/actual.length;
}
```

Comment: what if guess is shorter than actual?

Comment: You also don't need to use `char[]`, you can simply use `actual.charAt(counter)`

Comment: edited for shorter guess . Yes, `charAt` can be used instead.